# Web framework and entity-relationship model (ERM)

Tags: symfony1, content-management-system, entity-relationship, symfony-1.4, web-frameworks

I am currently designing a big website *a priori* based on a PostgreSQL database.

I have nearly ended the Entity Relationship Model and I am thinking about the way to develop (or have it develop) the whole thing (Java, PHP, other).

First I thought about a CMS to do the job. But this is a very specific (and big) project, and it would be better if I developed it entirely instead of trying to bow any CMS into my need.

1. Can I develop a website with any framework using my own ERM ?
2. Are there preconfigured ERMs with those frameworks (eventually for future projects) ?
3. I am thinking of CakePHP or Ruby on Rails. Would you encourage me into these directions ?

The website I am currently designing is supposed to be consulted by more than 1 000 000 times a day. As a consequence, I need scalability and strongness.

Thanks a lot by advance.

EDIT : I am thinking of taking Symfony. Can I do the same thing with this very framework ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended by making my ERM, and I work with Symfony2, which is a good Framework for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily implement any ERM in eZ Publish + Zeta Components + eZ Find (Solr) search engine.  And you get the rest of the functionality you'll need for 'free'.  Highly scalable architecture.
OSS license.  http://share.ez.no/download-develop/downloads

Comment: Thank you. Do you know whether this is the same thing with Symfony ?

Comment: No it is not the same. You'd need to do a lot more coding.